# Accessing a remote MySQL host with a hard-coded password

Tags: mysql, password

How to write a bash command for accessing a remote MySQL server?

If I try

```
    mysql -host 10.1.1.20 -port 3306 -u root -p 1234
```

it prompts the password and after I type in the password it considers `1234` as a database name and claims that there's no such database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `--password=` syntax, instead.  In fact, use the `--database=` syntax, as well.  In scripts, I prefer the explicit, long-form options, as they're more self-documenting.

Answer (score 3):

As Geoff Fritz said, you can use the `--password=` syntax, but that's insecure. You're better off using MySQL configuration files, like this:

```
[client]
password=your_pass
```

Name this file `.my.cnf`, put it in your home directory, and give it 600 permissions so that no one can you but read it. See the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-security-user.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the space between the "-p" and the password. i.e. -p1234